# creating on javascript to handle several radio buttons I want to hide after clicking them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a large form with several radio buttons. I want to display one question at a time. So I would need to use js to hide the div after the radio button is clicked. I have a working solution for each question, but I am hoping to create one script to load for all the questions whether than 25 separate scripts. Here is what I have:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('input[name="item_meta[12]').change(function () {
        var val1 = $("input[name='item_meta[12]']").val();
        if (val1 != "") {
            $('#frm_field_12_container').css('display', 'none');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $('input').change(function () {
      var currentIndex =  //get your integer from  a substring call here inside the name attribute or where the integer is found in the current element
        var val1 = $(this).val();
        if (val1 != "") {
            $('#frm_field_' + currentIndex + '_container').css('display', 'none');
        }
    });
```

You will have to make it specific to what you are doing, and clean it up, but this is the concept to use when doing a repetitious method on something.  My bad, you don't need the loop. Trying to answer while at work. :( Bad idea.

Comment: It will just take any input, [you make the input a selector that will select the inputs you want, maybe a class or something on it], and on the change event, you get the attribute that holds this specific inputs intgeger value. For example name="item_meat12. So you substring the 12 out of the name of the control, and set that as the "currentIndex" variable. See what I am saying.

Comment: Thanks Casey, I should have mentioned I am not a js guy. I can decipher some of what you popped up but I am not sure what a substring call would look like.